# Unable to locate package / apt-get command not found

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, libraries

Noob here, I've been researching on how to fix these problems for days now and I can't find exactly what I need to know, I need a walkthrough.

I'm trying to install Steam and here's what I get:

```
E: unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386
```

Press return to continue:

After that, this pops up:`

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6
```

So after doing lots of research I found I needed to download these packages or something, so i tried to, sudo apt-get , I got back that sudo apt-get command not found. So I've been researching and researching and I jut can't figure out what exactly I should do. Some people have gone into some details about different things to do but I'm completely lost.

If there's any information I should provide, let me know, I'm on chromebook running crouton, xfce4.

Comment: Wait... do I have to actually download Ubuntu or something?

Comment: Please explain exactly how you installed XFCE4. Links to instructions that you followed would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use? I know that 16.04 LTS (xenial xerus) have libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 and libc6:i386 in main repository (enabled by default). So `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386` will be enough here.

Comment: The question is too broad, trying to fix multiple things at once (Steam, apt-get, dpkg according to [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984224/unable-to-locate-package-apt-get-command-not-found#comment1583393_984229)). Please focus on one topic. Post exact commands you issue and their full output.

Answer (score 0):

Which isn't found, `apt-get` or `sudo`?

If `apt-get` doesn't work (For whatever reason), you could try `sudo apt` in place of `sudo apt-get` instead.

For installing the 32 bit libraries for Steam, try doing

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

in the terminal to add support for the :i386 packages first then running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

OR

```
sudo apt update
```

to update the lists of installable packages. Now, try installing Steam again.

Comment: dpkg command not found